# Почему не выводится окно?

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, c++

Здравствуйте! Осваиваю Directx и на первых парах не могу понять, почему не выводится окно?

```
#include<windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
             HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = 0;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (6);
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"class";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Теперь в операционной системе зарегистрирован новый класс окна и можно создать окно этого класса.

    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"class", L"заготовка программы",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        150, 100, 500, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // show wnd
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);    // В данной функции окну посылается сообщение WM_PAINT и оно может нарисовать себя.

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))    //главный обработчик событий
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);    //преобразование клавиатурного ввода
        DispatchMessage(&msg);    //обработка и пересылка сообщений в WinProc
    }
    return (msg.wParam);

    while (true) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Приложение запускается (видно в диспетчере задач), но ни окна, ни значка на панели нет...
В чем ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: >на первых парах

 В институте на первых парах что ли?

Comment: Не, сам...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При инициализации структуры wc еще надо сделать wc.cbWndExtra = 0; тогда окно появляется.
Вот рабочий исходник:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
             HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (6);
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = "class";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Теперь в операционной системе зарегистрирован новый класс окна и можно создать окно этого класса.

    hWnd = CreateWindow("class", "заготовка программы",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        150, 100, 500, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // show wnd
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);    // В данной функции окну посылается сообщение WM_PAINT и оно может нарисовать себя.

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))    //главный обработчик событий
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);    //преобразование клавиатурного ввода
        DispatchMessage(&msg);    //обработка и пересылка сообщений в WinProc
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Появилось!!!! Спасибо!!!!

Comment: При вызове ShowWindow ему посылаются сообщения WM_MOVE и WM_SIZE. При обработке сообщения WM_SIZE окну автоматически посылается сообщение WM_PAINT, поэтому UpdateWindow не нужен.

Comment: Видимо когда-то была заметна разница по времени прихода сообщения WM_PAINT при через очередь и при вызове UpdateWindow.

Answer (score 0):

А диспетчер задач какую загрузку ЦП показывает. Случайно не 100%? У тебя возникает бесконечный цикл из-за того, что ты игнорируешь сообщение WM_PAINT. Попробуй вообще убрать блок case WM_PAINT.

И ещё: то, что у тебя идёт после return (msg.wParam); никогда не будет выполняться. К тому же 2 цикла обработки сообщений не нужно.

UpdateWindow тоже не нужен. Он автоматически посылается при создании окна.

Comment: Нет, что-то не работает....(((( Можете кодом помочь?

Comment: WM_PAINT ни причем, он обрабатывается функцией DefWindProc. Без UpdateWindow вроде работает, но в "хрестоматийном" примере он есть.

Comment: >Ну не 100%, а 70%,.. я замечал это..

 У тебя наверное двухядерный процессор. Одно твоя программа загрузила и 20% другие процессы. А без WM_PAINT загрузка ЦП уменьшилась?